# how to pass a null value to a rdoQuery.rdoParameter in VisualBasic 5

Tags: sql-server, vb5

I have a visual basic 5 project, using Microsfot Remote Data Object 2.0

I have the following code:

```
Set ps = grdoCon.CreateQuery("Resolucion_ValidaCorrelatividad", SQL)

ps(0).Direction = rdParamReturnValue
ps(1).Direction = rdParamInput

ps.rdoParameters(1) = vbNull

ps.Execute
```

it gives me the following error:

(40002) 22005: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Valor de carácter no válido para especificación cast

something like

Invalid character value for cast specificaction...

I've already tried passing "null", vbEmpty, 0, false... but I had no luck...

any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops, silly me, it was easier than I thought...

just

ps.rdoParameters(1) = Null

...